# Ember.js RC2 deprecation warning: register("store", "main")

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After upgrading to Ember.js RC2 I get the following deprecation warning:

`DEPRECATION: register("store", "main") is now deprecated in-favour of register("store:main");`

What do I have to change in this minimal app to fix it?

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

Comment: hmm, have you tried using revision 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the newest version of `ember-data.js` and updating the code to:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

solves this problem. Thanks @finn-maccool !

Comment: didn't work for me... now it gives an exception: ```Uncaught Error: Error: The Ember Data library has had breaking API changes since the last time you updated the library. Please review the list of breaking changes at https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md, then update your store's `revision` property to 11``` but there is nothing there that could help me